# Simplest explanation of pendulum having a constant time period at low angles

Tags: harmonic-oscillator

What is the simplest explanation for the pendulum having a constant time period at low angles?

Comment: Can you give us some idea of what research you've already done in this area. Have you looked at any of the many descriptions of the pendulum out there in Googlespace?

Comment: I have researched google and most explanations give examples of trial runs or the formulae that relates time period with the length of the pendulum and the gravitational acceleration. But I cannot find an intuitive explanation for it that can be told to 3 or 4 graders to help them understand.

Comment: Assuming you mean independent with amplitude? The greater the amplitude of the oscillation the grater the acceleration and the faster (on average) it moves during one cycle then an oscillation with a smaller amplitude. This faster speed is just enough to make the period of the larger amplitude oscillation equal that of the smaller amplitude.

Comment: And how would you put this in mathematical terms in order to show that the difference in acceleration causes the time periods to match?

Comment: You would have to use differential equations, namely $\theta ''=-\frac{g}{l}\theta$ from which the time period can be obtained and which can be derived from $F=ma$

Comment: Could you expand on this explanation please. I would like to be able to explain these derivations simply to students.

Comment: 4th grade is age 9-10 isn't it? You're going to struggle to explain differential equations to children of that age.

Comment: I wouldn't try to derive anything for them. You can make them measure the time-period for small and large oscillations and see the difference experimentally. That is a lot of fun. It makes sense to show that the time period does NOT dependent on the mass, again done experimentally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The forces on a pendulum are shown in the diagram bellow:[image]

We are going to use $F=ma$ where in this case we will use angular acceleration and something called moment of inertia to replace mass (this is just like a rotational version of mass given by $ml^2$.) We also replace force with torque (or moment about an axis) in this case it is given by $F_g l sin \theta$. Where $F_g=mg$.
Thus we use $F=ma$ replacing the normal versions of force, mass and acceleration with their angular equivalents.

This gets us:
$$mgl sin\theta=ml^2\theta''$$
Dividing through gives us:
$$\frac{g}{l}sin\theta=\theta''$$
Now we assume that the maximum $\theta$ is small and use small angle approximations, that $\theta \approx sin \theta$. Meaning we get:
$$\frac{g}{l}\theta=\theta''$$
which is the general expression for SHM where $\omega^2=\frac{g}{l}$ and therefore since $T=\frac{2\pi}{\omega}$ we have $$T=2\pi \sqrt{\frac{l}{g}}$$
Which is independent of the amplitude of oscillation.
Now to my comment about the difference in acceleration. In our initial expression ($$mgl sin\theta=ml^2\theta''$$) the value $\theta$ depends only on $\theta''$. This means that since the time period is independent of the amplitude of oscillation that there is no other alternative that this is caused by a difference in acceleration. Otherwise if they had the same acceleration at their amplitudes say then the one with a smaller amplitude would have a smaller time period.

By the way I do agree with John's comment that this detail is a (far, far) to hard for 9 to 10 year olds.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest explanation is that for small $\theta$ the equation of motion $\theta''= \frac{g}{\ell} \sin\theta$ can be replaced by $\theta''= \frac{g}{\ell} \theta$ since $\sin\theta\approx\theta$. One can also provide a rigorous mathematical account for the intuitive idea that "period of infinitesimal oscillations is independent of the amplitude"; see [this article](http://arxiv.org/abs/1604.06663).